# Can we trust phrases on T-shirts as valid and sensible English sentences?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

Someone asked me about the meaning of

> I love second rate of sun

He says he saw it on a T-shirt (in Iran)

What could be the meaning of it?! Should we trust such sentences or they are more some cool phrases on T-shirts which may have not a sensible meaning?!

---

**Update**: some says that people do mistake and we can't trust any sentence, I know! but my main question is that is it possible that people (even native) deliberately use some irregular or even non sensual phrases as fashion (on cloths or etc.)!

To me, it is important to know because when I see some weird styles, I wonder if my English is not that good to understand the phrase, but if I doubt it could be a deliberate out-standard sentence I less question my knowledge of English!

Comment: T-shirts are not noted for meaningful content or accurate grammar and spelling. People think it's cool to wear things bearing writing in a language they don't understand. This is where it gets them... http://imgur.com/gallery/4Ap4EUO

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me unless it's a band name or something similar. I would expect '[second-rate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/second-rate)' to be an adjective and have a noun or noun phrase after it, not "of" after it.

Comment: @JavaLatte So true. At least they are just t-shirts and not [tattoos](http://imgur.com/gallery/fG33TMk).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no obvious meaning in English and is likely to be a nonsense phrase. If someone knows differently, please leave a comment and I will retract my close vote.

Comment: @ColleenV maybe, but it had some useful points that it has no meaning and we shouldn't trust T-shirt phrases! I change the title in this regard! Anyway I thought it has a meaning and for that I asked it.

Comment: I went ahead and retracted my close-vote. I was [on the fence](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+fence "unable to decide something") about it anyhow, because I think these sorts of questions are fine to ask, but once we say no, it doesn't mean anything there is usually not much more to explain.

Comment: And I gave you an up-vote for including where your friend saw the t-shirt. It was an important clue that it might not mean anything.

Comment: What about "سرعت ثانیه ای خورشید". Seems like a bad translation. Or mybe its a brand.

Comment: @JamesWirth It's actually a happy thing when we can edit a question to bring it on-topic so quickly - I probably wouldn't have up-voted before the editing :) Some might still believe it should be closed, but I think it falls under "practical problems encountered while learning English".

Comment: Related question (from a hoodie, not a t-shirt): [What is the meaning of “…you don't know you have in ways you can't understand”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/46274/9161)

Comment: @ColleenV The answer to this question (can we trust...?) is "it depends." And I think any question that could generate the very answer should be closed as "primarily opinion-based" or "unclear". Especially when an example sentence doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Rathony I can see both why this question should remain open, and why it should be closed, so I've retracted my close vote and will let other folks decide. I do think the answer is "no, you can't trust language printed on clothes to be good, grammatical, well-punctuated English." but there is maybe a little more to say about it.

Comment: Regarding your question update, it's not just possible: it happens. As I already said in my answer, people use bad grammar on purpose for effect.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah you did, and I just needed a little bit more explanation of this trend

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the fashion industry. *"is it possible that people (even native) deliberately use some irregular or even non sensual phrases as fashion?"* Yes, it's possible. This is now about fashion, not English.

Comment: How is this about fashion? It's natural for English learners to wonder whether a sentence or whatever printed on some item is actually grammatically correct or not. Because we want to know what the printed sentence/phrase means if it does mean something and we think the reason why we cannot get the meaning of whatever is printed is maybe because of our poor English.

Comment: @AlanCarmack as @ Miki pointed and I also said in the question, its not something that a fashion designer seeks to know, (or even he seeks), it is a question of an English learner (and for this it is on-topic), because our job (as learners) is to get familiar with anything we think we don't understand it and to know the borders!

Comment: @Ahmad  Their rules are THE RULES. So they will most likely ignore our comments no matter what we say. Let's just leave this as is.

Comment: @Miki Actually I agree that this is not about fashion and you shouldn't feel like there is an 'us' and 'them'. We are all one community - without people asking questions the people answering questions have no purpose. If you feel like this was incorrectly closed, you can always ask for people to reopen it by making a post on [meta] explaining why the question is on-topic or asking for some help to bring it on-topic so it can be re-opened. This isn't the first question that has been asked about something printed on a shirt that didn't make sense.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for your comment. I think I will let Ahmed decide what to do with this question. Since you told me that this wasn't the first question about something printed on a shirt, now I think it's fair for it to be put on hold regardless. Thank you for your guidance :)

Comment: @Miki After reading my comment again, I think my last sentence could be interpreted two different ways. What I meant to say was "This isn't the first question about something that didn't make sense that was printed on a shirt. The question makes perfect sense in my opinion :)

Comment: @ColleenV  You are right! And I find this kind of thinking very pleasurable. My teacher didn't call me an English freak when I was in high school for nothing after all :-P Haha.

Answer (score 4):

> Can we trust phrases on T-shirts as valid and sensible English sentences?

No, of course not. There is no government T-shirt Grammar Department regulating t-shirt designs to ensure they make sense.

More broadly:

> Can we trust phrases [that we see or hear anywhere] as valid and sensible English sentences?

No. People make mistakes. People use bad grammar on purpose for effect. Even books about grammar sometimes contain grammatical errors.

> I love second rate of sun

This doesn't make any sense in English - unless "Second Rate Of Sun" is the name of a band or something like that, in which case the phrase "Second Rate Of Sun" doesn't seem to make any sense itself, but the phrase "I love Second Rate Of Sun" would make sense.

Given that this was seen on a t-shirt in Iran, I would guess that somebody got a translation into English wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what it means.

No, you can't trust t-shirts.

Answer to question update:

Anything is possible in the world of t-shirts.

It seems to me that the language and symbols on most t-shirts are meant to communicate a message. Maybe some t-shirt makers rely on gibberish or gobbledegook to get a message across. Maybe some t-shirts don't want to have a  message. Maybe their message is syntactical error. Anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You see lots of items with English words or sentences on them that don't make sense at all or that are inappropriate in many countries whose first languages are not English.

I was shopping for my son's clothes once, and found a really cute T-shirt. I was thinking if I should buy it or not until I noticed a print which said "hideous". I was like heck no! and I put it back. I've seen some weird or wrong chinese characters written on T-shirts in the US, too.

So, in my opinion, don't trust those phrases too much!  If you're interested, take a look at this site. It shows you some signs that are found in Japan: https://globalechos.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/japenglish-funny-japanese-interpretation-of-english/